# Cannot read from table (SQL and PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, authentication

I've been trying to create a login form for my website but the form seems unable to connect to the table or retrieve info from it. I even tried obtaining some sample code online, but it is still not being able to connect. Here's the code:

```
session_start(); 
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is empty";
    } else {    
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);   

        $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "cpses_company");

        $query = mysqli_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
            header("location: profile.php"); 
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";   
        }

        mysqli_close($connection); 
    }
}
```

No matter what values I insert, I keep getting the error code "Username or Password is invalid". The table does contain values and I get this error even when I am inserting the values correctly. I am assuming that it is unable to connect to the database or the table. Any ideas?

edit: HTML (index.php)

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
{
header("location: profile.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>PHP Login Session Example</h1>
<div id="login">
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need to see the HTML form that goes with this

Comment: I downvoted because you presented poor code with no error checking, which would have saved you a lot of headache. Read the note by @anant kumar singh

Comment: Too many things wrong with this question, 3 major issues (possibly 4) not to mention plain text storage and a few unknowns. Also, not interacting with anyone in the comments area. Answers given below are all incorrect. For that I've voted to close the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Have you tried refreshing the page? I did answer the people that helped me in the comment section. I'm sorry if I can't answer everyone in 20 seconds, I am still learning php and I'm no expert. I thought this site was for questions and answers, not for judging how much or how fast we interact in the comment area...

Comment: please remove  `$username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);` lines

Comment: I sure hope this isn't meant to go live. You also been asked to post the form for this 22 mins. prior to this comment, in your question and not in comments area.

Comment: *"not for judging how much or how fast we interact in the comment area"* - we're not your personal valets; sorry but people have better things to do than wait. Plus, I don't "judge" people, I judge "code" and what's been posted. When something is "unclear" such as your question is/was, then that's what the comments section is for (wink), to try and get more relevant and important information (wink). Which I might add, had you posted your HTML form right away, would have expedited the process, and I for one would have been able to give you a "solution" within "seconds" of your post.

Comment: and again, I hope this isn't intended to go **live**, not with what you're using. I can guarantee that you will get hacked. So, if this is just a learning curve and not going live; great. Otherwise do NOT use this code. I'm the only one who has raised this RED flag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wow! I wish I had your speed and skills to answer so quickly and efficiently. Maybe someday I will reach your level of coding superiority. And yes no one is my personal valet. No one obliged you to provide an answer for me. There are a lot of nice people who have already answered with correct answers and didn't have to go through all of the process that you just went through...and you still didn't provide an answer (wink).

Comment: When one has worked in "hell's kitchen", things have got to move and fast. I'll even go "the extra mile", provided I know what I'm dealing with, rather than ask 22 questions before I get the "full picture". Not to brag, but I could have solved your question within "1 minute" after you posted your question. Instead, it took an hour for others. The "added bonus" would have been the fact about lack of security and would have provided you with "safe" code, rather than leaving your users and your site, open to getting hacked. Yeah, I like it when people feel that "sense of security" (wink).

Comment: Good for you m8! Good for you. I feel more secure now thank you @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for your guidance . Always learn new thing from your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exist here:-

```
$query = mysqli_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
```

You need make `$connection` as first parameter like this:-

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
```

**Note:- try always to use `mysql error reporting` so that you will get rid of  the problem like you are facing. for that you need to do like below very simple:-**

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Some other issue are there, so for your help, Please try like this:-

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is empty";
    } else {    
        //$username=$_POST['username'];
        //$password=$_POST['password'];

        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass","cpses_company"); // direct give db name here
 // remove that two line what i said in comment also
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);   


        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        //$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);//comment this line
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
            header("location: profile.php"); 
            exit;
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";   
        }

        mysqli_close($connection); 
    }
}  
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and help anant. I tried what you mentioned, but I am still getting the same "Username or password is invalid" error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Anant, thank you for your help. I removed the lines like you suggested previously and the code now works. Thanks again !

Comment: this won't work `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);` and for 2 reasons - same for `where password=$password AND username=$username"` also `if ($query->num_rows > 0)` which is an object oriented method.

Comment: it's still incorrect as per your edit. did you not go over my comment above in its entirety? the `where` clause

Comment: sorry @freed-ii i looked to that right now  and just thinking to edit it. million thanks to you and sorry for inconvenience for you.

Comment: really helpful you are. i am so sorry again and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As mysqli_query need paramater like this:-

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Read [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

So your `mysqli_query` would be:-

First parameter `connection` then `query`

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
```

**UPDATED**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is empty";
    } else {    
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass","cpses_company"); // direct give db name here
 // remove that two line what i said in comment also
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$password);   


        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        //$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);//comment this line
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
            header("location: profile.php"); 
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";   
        }

        mysqli_close($connection); 
    }
}  
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help saty. I tried what you mentioned above, but it still didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: also remove `$username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);`this line from your code

Comment: also use `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);`

Comment: Saty, here is the html embedded in the index.php file:

Comment: have you check my suggestion and apply??

Comment: saty, I removed the $username = stripslashes($username); $password = stripslashes($password); codes and the program now works. Thanks so much for your time and help!

Comment: @JayBlanchard yaa you are write.  I always  learn new thing from other mistake that's informant for me.

Comment: This answer would have been so much better if the query had been parametrized, grandly reducing the possibility for SQL injection. And in this day and age if we're going to create logins we should [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).